# Javascript Function passing php varaibles

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with the code

`<script type="text/javascript"> test(<?php echo $i;?>)</script>`

If I passed some other variable as mentioned above  it's working

but not working  for below code

`<script type="text/javascript">test(<?php echo $row['name'];?>)</script>`

Comment: And where's the code ?!

Comment: Thats totally unclear what you asking. You not "mentioned any variables above", we don't know, what `test` function does, what is the error, what is the desired output?

Comment: Assuming name is a string `test('<?php echo $row['name'];?>')`

Comment: have you check what value return by you $row['name'];array.

Comment: store $row['name'] into one variable and then try

Comment: Where is the `$i` come from, where is the `$row['name']` come from, please show the relevant codes, we can not help you without that.

Comment: Please provide the full code

Answer (score 0):

pass it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">test("<?php echo $row['name'];?>")</script>
```